# Set WPF ComboBox Selected Item Color to the Color of the ComboBox Item

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, foreground

My combobox is bound to a list of states. The state have a column participating which when true the comboitem foreground color should be red. This works fine. But when I select the combobox item with foreground color red, it loses that foreground color and sets it to black. Can somebody help me point out what I am doing wrong?

```
<ComboBox Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}},Path=Foreground}"
          DisplayMemberPath="StateName" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding States}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Model.StateID}" SelectedValuePath="StateID" >
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding DoesNotParticipate, Converter={StaticResource NonParticipatingConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

The binding you set for your `ComboBoxe`s `Foreground` prop is looking for a `ComboBoxItem` typed ancestor in the visual tree, but the item you need is the descendant of the `ComboBox`. Especially the `ComboBoxes SelectedItem`.

**EDIT**

Since you bind the item to model objects the ComboBox.SelectedItems type would be this model objects type. Which means - probably - they don't have Foreground property.

I recommend the following:
It seems to me that DoesNotParticipate is a boolean prop so don't use `Converter`, use instead `Trigger`:

```
<ComboBox Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}},Path=Foreground}"
      DisplayMemberPath="StateName" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding States}" 
      SelectedValue="{Binding Model.StateID}" SelectedValuePath="StateID" >
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem.DoesNotParticipate}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style> 
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Property={Binding DoesNotParticipate} Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```